# Best Database Design for Circular Relations

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-5

I have a following Class Diagram:

```
Customer

Id
Name
Email
```

```
Packages

Id
Name
ImageUrl
Price
Description
Products (One package may have 1 to many products)
```

```
Products

Id
Name
ImageUrl
Price
Description
```

```
Orders

Id
CustomerId
Address
```

How i can make relationship between Orders, Products and Packages. I am using Entity Framework 6 Code First with MVC 5 webapi.

**Edited:**

- Customer can place multiple orders, One order is only associated with one customer
- One order can contain multiple Products, One product may have multiple orders
- Customer can order multiple Packages, One package can be ordered by multiple customers
- Thanks

Comment: It depends on the relations you want between them. How they related?

Comment: What circular relation?

Comment: Also, "asp.net [anything]" is not an appropriate tag here; if desired add in "entity-framework" or the particular modeling/mapping tool used as applicable.

Comment: @venerik I have edited my question with more info.

Comment: Are you sure you want to link packages directly to a customer? As you state, a customer can _order_ multiple packages. I'd replace the third bullet with: One order can contain multiple Packages, one   Package can have multiple orders.

Comment: Customer can order both Packages (you can say hot deals) and any product from Menu.
customer can order packages, how i should save that information so that i will get that order in orders table? For example, one customer can order multiple packages (i.e. package 1, package 2) and multiple products (burger, cold drink). So, his order will be package 1 + package 2 + burger + cold drink. This is one order so how i will save this as order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Customer` - `Orders` have a one to many relationship. Will require ForeignKey `CustomerId` in `Orders`. So the above should do.
2. `Orders` - `Products` have a many to many relationship. Will require a many to many table (say, `RelatedOrderProducts`) with Foreign Key fields `OrderId` and `ProductId` of tables `Orders` and `Products` resp.
3. `Customer` and `Packages` are also a many to many relationship. So same as above there should be a many to many table (`RelatedPackagesCustomers`) with foreign key fields `PackageId` and `CustomerId` of tables `Packages` and `Customers` respectively.

I am not familiar with the Entity Framework, MVC, but this is a database design you may follow.

**EDIT:**

I may have misunderstood the third relationship. There are a few fixes that may work depending upon how you wish to access the data. One possible edit is to change the `RelatedPackagesCustomers` table to `RelatedOrderPackages` table and the Foreign keys accordingly. This way you will have two relations, order-packages and order-products that will save your order having combination of packages and products.

To save you should add a order and use the `OrderId` to add products and package relations in their resp. relation tables.

When you need to get a list of all the packages and products that a customer has ordered till date, you will do a query of `Order` with `CustomerId` and over it do two `JOIN` queries that will fetch you the packages from `RelatedOrderPackages` and products from the `RelatedOrderProducts` related to the particular `OrderId` (indirectly related to the customer).

Comment: Thanks hooSein, tell me one thing that customer can order packages, how i should save that information so that i will get that order in orders table? For example, one customer can order multiple packages (i.e. package 1, package 2) and multiple products (burger, cold drink). So, his order will be package 1 + package 2 + burger + cold drink. This is one order so how i will save this as order.

Comment: I that case it will be circular relation: i.e Order has relation with products which has relation with packages which has relation with order again.

Comment: No, it won't. You should not go from products to packages. The relation between those entities is from package to products.

Comment: In any case it would be many to many relation between products and packages and hence i will end up again with circular relation.